# Why does Redis server keep writing info to the log even when no one is using it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching, redis, stackexchange.redis

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 base application written using c#. I am trying to use Redis servers on windows to cache data.

I installed Redis on my local machine. Then I installed https://github.com/imperugo/StackExchange.Redis.Extensions package to allow me to interact with the server easily.

I am noticing that the Redis server keep writing to it's own log file which is growing very fast. Here is an example of an log that is written to the log over and over (almost every second)

```
[9232] 15 Aug 12:42:49 - DB 10: 3 keys (0 volatile) in 4 slots HT.
[9232] 15 Aug 12:42:49 - 0 clients connected (0 slaves), 1180456 bytes in use
```

While Redis is writing no one is using it (accessing data from it)

Why does it keep writing repeated info to its log? Is this a normal behavior or a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is loglevel set to verbose on the command line or within the redis.conf file? You could try setting loglevel to notice or warning.